# Cocos2D setDisplayFrame not working after view change?

Tags: ios, image, cocos2d-iphone, sprite

In my Cocos2D app I have a sprite sheet with all of my game's objects. In the init method of the CCLayer class I do this:

```
[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] addSpriteFramesWithFile:@"Objects.plist"];
objectsSheet = [CCSpriteBatchNode batchNodeWithFile:@"Objects.pvr.ccz"];
[self addChild:objectsSheet];
```

And I create my main character sprite like so:

```
mySprite = [[CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"MainImage.png"] retain];
```

And it loads fine.  When the character dies ***before*** I leave the view I do this:

```
CCSpriteFrameCache* cache = [CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache];
CCSpriteFrame* frame = [cache spriteFrameByName:@"NewImage.png"];
[mySprite setDisplayFrame:frame];
```

That even works good. Now I leave the view and then later on I come BACK to the game view.

So now I have to change the character image back to its original image so I do this:

```
[mySprite setDisplayFrame:[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] spriteFrameByName:@"MainImage.png"]];
```

*But something odd happens*, mySprite is just blank, that last code above definitely gets called but doesn't do anything. The odd thing is, if I load it into a NEW sprite that was created after I switched back to the game view, I see the image. So it has to do with the old image not being remembered or something.

Does anyone know why this is happening or how I can fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you explain what is `view` and `come BACK to the game view`?

Comment: I integrate UIKit with Cocos2D just like in Ray Wenderlich's tutorial. So my game view is a CCGLView in a UIViewController then when the character dies I switch view controllers to another UIViewController. Then I switch back to the game view UIViewController

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that after you return to the game view

```
[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] spriteFrameByName:@"MainImage.png"]
```

is not `nil`. Frame may be unload from spriteframe cache

Comment: It is nil, how can I add it back to the spriteframe cache?

Comment: You can retain it. In this case it will not be removed from cache. Just don't forget to release it when it does not need. Or call addSpriteFramesWithFile: again before this line of code